# Is it harmful to use Shell Super Petrol for my Honda Activa?

Tags: honda, motorcycle

I live in India.

I ride a 2 wheeler named Honda Activa. Here are the specifications : http://www.honda2wheelersindia.com/activa/specifications.html

I use **Shell Super Petrol**. Here are the details : 
http://www.shell.com/ind/products-services/on-the-road/fuels/unleaded-fe2-tpkg/overview.html

Some people told me that these 2 are not compatible and I may even end up harming my engine.

Can anyone go through the info provided in the links above and tell me if something is obviously not compatible here?

Comment: I think you will need a notable claim that it is harmful.  For what it is worth I do not see any thing that screams will damage engine in the linked pages.  Though it looks like it is formulated to work on Indian spec engines which your Honda engine will not be.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a read of the other questions here on the qualities of petrols with different octane ratings.

Basically higher octane fuels will not give your engine any real benefit, and are likely to just make your engine run less efficiently and cost more to run.

You should not do damage to your engine but I would advise using ordinary fuel anyway to save money.

Comment: Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5) to support your claims.